# Android error "IF" and "ELSE"

Tags: java, android, listview, if-statement, arraylist

I'm new at Android and I am having a problem with my code.

the software is not showing "Fail" when the user presses the wrong block.

When I debug the code, it is only running the if part, not the else. I want to execute the else condition as well, any suggestions?

```
private void buttonLogic(View v) {
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; 1 <= curLevel; i++) {
            if(i!=12)
            tempList.add(buttons.get(i));
           else
                break;
        }
        if (tempList.contains(v.getTag())) {
            curGuess++;
            checkWin();

        } else {
            lostGame();
        }
    }

 private void lostGame () {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        disableButtons();
        b_new.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; 1 <= curLevel; i++) {` is that an infinite loop? What is `curLevel`? Why are you testing `1` against it?

Comment: Check your for-loop parameters. I guess you wanted to put 'i' instead of '1'.

Comment: It is a memory game application, after the game starts will be displayed inside blocks (4X3) the number 0 for a few seconds,  then the user has to memorize it and then press the right order. If the user types the right order he will be moved  to the next level (curLevel) there are 12 Levels. IF not (else) a message "Fail" will be displayed and the game will restart. (Only the else part it is not working at the moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, I really hope **curLevel** has been declared/initialized somewhere outside the method you pasted.

Moving on... Your error lies in your for-loop parameters. I guess you intended to put 'i' instead of '1'. The statement `1 <= curLevel` would probably always return true (if curLevel is >= 1) and your code might never proceed to the next instruction. Your for-loop is supposed to look this way:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= curLevel; i++) {
        if(i!=12)
        tempList.add(buttons.get(i));
       else
            break;
    }
```

Re-run it and your code should run fine. I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your if condition. it is an infinite loop.

```
for (int i = 0; 1 <= curLevel; i++) {
```

1 for most cases less than curLevel and if not, curLevel will be 0 or 1, so "i" will be at most 0!

what do you want?

I think you have to put "i" instead of 1

```
for (int i = 0;i <= curLevel; i++) {
```